# Post data from radio buttons and check boxes into database

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form on a webpage that has radio buttons and a check box, and i'm trying to get that data inserted to a database when the form is submitted.  When I submit the form the fields remain unchanged (default entry.  All the other entries are inserted, just these two are giving me issues.

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  gender varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  specialmem BOOL NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sex">Gender:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female" ) echo "checked";?>
    value="female">Female
    <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male" ) echo "checked";?>value="male">Male
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="specialmem">Are you a Special member?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialmem" class="form-control" id="specialmem" value="1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Insert to database:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    $gender= $_POST['gender'];
    $specialmem= $_POST['specialmem'];
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO users (gender, specialmem) VALUES ('$gender','$specialmember')";
}
```

Comment: so where is the code that executes the query? just writing a query doesn't execute it..

Comment: google how to use PDO, there are a thousand posts on SO about it.

Comment: There is a button that submits the form. Other fields are submitted no problem, just the check box and radio buttons aren't.

Comment: The browser does not send UNCHECKED checkboxes to the PHP script. You need to use `isset($_POST['specialmem'])` to know if it was checked or not

Comment: That is in my code?

Comment: you are not set value in check box try it like that
        <input type="checkbox" name="specialmem" class="form-control" id="specialmem" value="special" >

i preffer to use 1 or 0 in database for check special

Comment: I used value="1" and that check box works now.  But I can't get the value from the radio buttons to post correctly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace html code with the below code and then try it again

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sex">Gender:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" 
        <?php if(isset($gender)) { 
            if($gender='female') { 
                echo 'selected'; 
            } 
        } ?>
    >Female
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" 
        <?php if(isset($gender)) { 
            if($gender='male') { 
                echo 'selected'; 
            } 
        } ?>
    >Male
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="specialmem">Are you a Special member?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="specialmem" value="1" class="form-control" id="specialmem" placeholder="">
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['specialmem'])) {
            if ($_POST['specialmem'] == '1') {
                $specialmem = $_POST['specialmem'];
            } else {
                $specialmem=0;
            }                   
        } 
    ?>
    <button type="submit" name="submitted" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox form you use will produce a $_POST string "on" if checked:
`$_POST = array(["specialmem"]=> "on")`

Your database however, is a BOOLEAN. You need to do an extra step for that, like:
`if($_POST["specialmem"] == "on"){
$specialmem =1; // the value to insert
}`

Plus the variable you try to insert into the database is called '$specialmember', should be '$specialmem'

Your gender radio button code seems to be OK. It should work.